# Qual è il significato di "cincischiare" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, word-meaning

In *Sul far del giorno*, una "cosmicomica" di Italo Calvino ho letto:

> Mi ci volle un po' di tempo a rendermi conto, a tastoni, che mia sorella, *cincischiando* con questa specie di mota, aveva tirato su una montagnola tutta pinnacoli, merlature e guglie.

L'azione ha luogo nel momento in cui le nebule di gas e polveri che era nostro sistema solare comincia a condensarsi (per questa ragione è tutto buio: il sole non esiste ancora) e quindi a formare materia solida. La sorella di Qfwfq, il narratore della storia, ha stato giocando con questa nuova materia solida per costruire "cose" (fino a quel momento non esistevano le "cose" poiché tutto era materia gassosa).

Ho cercato "cincischiare" nei dizionari e ho trovato che significa tagliare, spiegazzare, sgualcire... Comunque tutto questo non sembra avere molto senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste dirmi cosa significa "cincischiare" nella frase precedente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nel caso specifico significa grossomodo "perdere tempo senza concludere nulla" (l'espressione è molto popolare in Toscana); probabilmente anche nel contesto specifico risulta che effettivamente una montagnola tutta pinnacoli, merlature e guglie sia di poco utilizzo; citando [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cincischiare/):

> 3. Usato assol., perder tempo in lavori senza concluder nulla: è un’ora che stai cincischiando!

Quindi la frase in oggetto potrebbe essere benissimo parafrasata come:

> Mi ci volle un po' di tempo a rendermi conto, a tastoni, che mia sorella, *perdendo tempo senza concludere nulla* con questa specie di mota, aveva tirato su una montagnola tutta pinnacoli, merlature e guglie.

Answer (score 1):

Non conosco il contesto più ampio del brano, ma penso che si riferisca al significato riportato sotto di fare qualcosa tanto per fare, giusto per far passare il tempo.

Sembra che la sorella, ***giocherellando con la sabbia bagnata***, abbia  fatto uno di quei piccoli castelli di sabbia che i bambini fanno sulle spiagge.

***[Cincischiare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/cincischiare.php):***

> - Agire, operare di malavoglia: cincischia da ore senza risultato
>     || Perdere tempo in modo inconcludente. (Hoepli)

[image]