# Significato di "cincischiare" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Quell’antica ragazza* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Andai a coricarmi nella stalla, ma non dormii, vegliai dimenandomi sulla paglia finché sentii Eugenio di ritorno, che 
>   **cincischiava** all’uscio come un cieco o un ubriaco.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "cincischiare" in questa frase. Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cincischiare) ho trovato che questo verbo può significare:

> **2.** Di parole, smozzicarle, pronunciarle male. **3.** Usato assol., perder tempo in lavori senza concluder nulla: *è un’ora che stai cincischiando!*

Ora, l'accezione numero 2 avrebbe senso per un ubriaco che non è capace di pronunciare bene le parole, ma non vedo perché un cieco non dovrebbe parlare bene. Per quanto riguarda l'accezione numero 3, non sono sicura di averla capito bene: cosa significa "lavori" nella spiegazione del Treccani? Fa riferimento al fatto di lavorare su qualcosa (per esempio, su un compito scolastico o "su una montagnola tutta pinnacoli" come si spiega in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5778)) o di fare un'attività per guadagnare uno stipendio? Se è così, non capisco perché si paragoni il lavoro improduttivo di questo Eugenio con quello di un cieco o di un ubriaco. "Cincischiare" può significare semplicemente fare qualcosa per far passare il tempo senza necessità di lavorare su qualcosa?

Comment: Propenderei per un uso ampliato di *cincischiare*: un ubriaco ha tipicamente difficoltà a infilare la chiave nella toppa per aprire la porta. Un cieco no, in genere, ma ci sono pregiudizi al riguardo.

Comment: @egreg: Quindi, il significato potrebbe essere quello di fare male, con esitazioni e incertezze, il "lavoro" di aprire la porta?

Comment: Mi pare proprio.

Comment: Veramente ha senso, @egreg.

Answer (score 4):

Nel contesto da te citato *cincischiare* significa perdere tempo, bighellonare, comportarsi in maniera indolente.

Dal [*Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana*, Vol. 3, pag. 150](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000156.jpg) per "cincischiare":

> **5.**  Figur.  Far  male  un  lavoro,  con  mille  esi­tazioni  e  incertezze.  -  Anche  assol.:  **indugiare, perdere  tempo  in  discorsi,  in  azioni  inconclu­denti, senza sapersi decidere**.

Comment: Quindi, il significato sarebbe che tanto questo Eugenio come il cieco o l'ubriaco di cui parla il testo lasciavano passare il tempo in modo indolente senza far nulla di profitto, no?

Comment: Esatto, il significato è perdere tempo in attività improduttive. In campagna c'é sempre qualcosa di utile da fare in qualunque stagione.

Comment: Stavo per accettare questa risposta, ma poi quello che ha detto @egreg (mi sembra più concorde con il fatto di trovarsi all'uscio e con il paragone con l'ubriaco e il cieco) mi ha fatto dubitare.

Answer (score 1):

Probabilmente Fenoglio adopera *cincischiare* in un senso ampliato rispetto alle definizioni dei dizionari citati e che è, a mio sentire, piuttosto comune: *fare qualcosa che è inutile allo scopo prefisso o è solo una perdita di tempo*.

Nella situazione descritta, il protagonista sente arrivare Eugenio perché costui si trova in difficoltà ad aprire la porta come succede tipicamente agli ubriachi che non riescono a centrare la toppa con la chiave e fanno rumore strisciandola sulla porta in cerca del buco, con movimenti impacciati.

<sup>Fenoglio dice “cieco o ubriaco”, ma nella mia esperienza i ciechi sono perfettamente in grado di centrare la toppa con la chiave senza tentativi inutili. Credo che sia caduto nello stereotipo del cieco che va in giro tendendo le braccia e urtando cose e angoli. Niente di più sbagliato. Una volta un mio collega cieco mi chiese di accompagnarlo con il motorino, si sedette dietro e mi indicò la strada che conoscevo solo fino a un certo punto. L'organista cieco della mia parrocchia raccontava che, dopo il bombardamento del '44, guidava quelli che non riconoscevano i posti per via dei crolli.</sup>

Comment: Forse, più che il fatto che Fenoglio sia caduto in questo stereotipo, è un modo di descrivere la mentalità dell'io narrante in questo racconto (l'autore scrive di questa storia: «Raccontata, a una festa di parenti in Murazzano, da Teobaldo Fenoglio, l’unico dei nostri che sia stato a servizio. Io l’ascoltai di straforo.»).

Comment: Magari in certo senso questo significato rientrerebbe nel «Far male un lavoro, con mille esi­tazioni e incertezze» del GDLI.